# How to filter and delete a record that has a specific attribute

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

Im trying filter records with that has a specific value key and delete them. I tried "withFields" and "hasFields" but seems that i can't apply delete to them. My question is how can i do that?

Comment: Can you post your `hasFields` query? That should be the one you want to use.

Comment: r.db('databaseFoo').table('bar').hasFields('id').delete()

Comment: it returns the following error: RqlRuntimeError: Expected type SELECTION but found SEQUENCE:
VALUE SEQUENCE in:
r.db("databaseFoo").table("bar").hasFields("id").delete()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Actually, that makes total sense. It's a known issue in RethinkDB: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2609. Updated my answer to give a better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
r.db('databaseFoo').table('checkpoints').filter(function (user) {
    return user('type').default(false);
}).delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all documents that have a `type` key, you can use `hasFields` for that.

```
r.db('databaseFoo').table('checkpoints')
 .hasFields('type')
```

In your current query, what you are doing is getting all documents that don't have a `type` key or where the value for `type` is equal to `false`. This might be what you want, but it's a little confusing if you only want documents that have a `type` property.

**Keeping a reference to the original document**

The problem with using `hasFields` is that it converts a selection (a sequence with a reference to the specific rows in the database) that you can `update`, and `delete` into a sequence, with which you can't do that. This is a known [issue in RethinkDB](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2609). You can read [this blog post](http://blog.hiphipjorge.com/data-types-in-rethinkdb-whats-the-difference/) to understand the different types in ReQL a bit better.

In order to get around this, you can use the `hasFields` method with the `filter` method.

```
r.db('databaseFoo').table('checkpoints')
 .filter(r.row.hasFields('type'))
 .delete()
```

This query will work since it returns a selection which can then be passed into `delete`.

---

If you want to get all records with with a specific value at a specific key, you can do so a couple of different ways. To get all documents where the property `type` is equal to `false`, you can do as follows:

```
r.db('databaseFoo').table('checkpoints')
 .filter({ type: false })
```

or, you can do:

```
r.db('databaseFoo').table('checkpoints')
 .filter(r.row('type').eq(false))
```